# openRTSP recording with segmentation

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, recording, ip-camera

I have an IP camera with RTSP streaming. I want to use my Raspberry Pi as a recorder. The idea is:

- Pi is starting;
- After boot, Pi should automatically start recording stream and saving it with h.264 codec;
- When file reach 100MB or 1 hour, Pi starts recording it to a new one;

But I don't know how to do this...

I've tried to use command:

```
openRTSP rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.108:554/cam/realmonitor -w 1280 -h 720 -f 15 -P 3600 -i /home/pi/nagrania/MyVdeoFFmpeg.avi
```

But I've only received:

```
Usage: openRTSP [-p <startPortNum>] [-r|-q|-4|-i] [-a|-v] [-V] [-d <duration>] [-D <max-inter-packet-gap-time> [-c] [-S <offset>] [-n] [-O] [-t|-T <http-port>] [-u <username> <password>] [-s <initial-seek-time>] [-z <scale>] [-w <width> -h <height>] [-f <frames-per-second>] [-y] [-H] [-Q [<measurement-interval>]] [-F <filename-prefix>] [-b <file-sink-buffer-size>] [-B <input-socket-buffer-size>] [-I <input-interface-ip-address>] [-m] <url> (or openRTSP -o [-V] <url>)
```

What am I doing wrong? Using any parameter causes displaying this hint.

I've also tried VLC, but I couldn't set segmentation for it and the file size incrementation was too fast.

I use Raspberry Pi with the lates Raspbian installed.

Answer (score 3):

```
openRTSP -i -u {User} {Password} -w 1080 -h 720 -f 15 -P 3600  "rtsp://192.168.1.108:554/cam/realmonitor" > /home/pi/nagrania/MyVideoFFmpeg.avi
```

I think this should work for you. Depending on your stream you may consider using -4 instead of -i to output as mp4 instead of avi. Change the file extension of your file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'u' flag to provide username and passowrd, try the following:-

openrtsp -u USER PASSWORD -w 1080 -h 720 -D 60 "rtsp://192.168.1.108:554/cam/realmonitor"

This should give you a file one minute long of a video capture.
Once you confirmed this works, you can then specify output file names/location

Comment: Thx, I'll try this as soon as I would get access to the server once again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better way as the above command using `-P` does not output to the filename specified and instead has its own filenaming convention `output-00000-03600` etc, explained in the manual what -P does

> -P This option instructs "openRTSP" to generate a new output file every  seconds. (Each output file's name will
> include the time range (in seconds) that it represents.)

This script below is quick and easy way to record for 1 hour and restart the script itself until you manually CTRL+C - this uses a much simpler `-d duration` you can set the time to anything you like. Change the rtsp link to suit yours and also the ending bash statement location of your script so it can re-run itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
# record.sh

recordtime=3600 #1 hour
filename=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H_%S")
user=user
password=password

openRTSP -i -u ${user} ${password} -w 1080 -h 720 -f 15 -d ${recordtime} "rtsp://192.168.1.111:554/1/h264major" > ${filename}.avi

bash /home/user/record.sh #change to where your script is

exit 0
```